# Error: File "python", line 31, in organise TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Tags: python

I'm a very unexperienced programmer, so my code is probably extremely messy, but I'm trying to code something that gets the direction of each pixel in a p by p square. Each pixel van be black or white, 1 or 0, and is in list x. I don't understand why it throws this error now, because I only changed one thing. Before, all the 'if's were 'elif's, but I switched it to 1 else and for the rest if's so 1 pixel can have more than 1 direction. Thanks for the help!

PS: Sorry for the super messy post and code, I hope some of you will get what I'm saying.

```
def organise(x):
for n in range(len(x)-2*p):
    if x[n] !=1:
        direc.append(0)
    else:    
        if (x[n-2*p-1] == 1 and x[n-p-1]==1) or (x[n-2*p-1] == 1 and x[n-p]==1) or (x[n-2*p] == 1 and x[n-p]==1) or (x[n-2*p+1]== 1 and x[n-p]==1) or (x[n-2*p+1]== 1 and x[n-p+1]==1):
            direc.append(1)
        if x[n-2*p+2]== 1 and x[n-p+1]==1: 
            direc.append(2)
        if (x[n-p+2]==1 and x[n-p+1]==1) or (x[n-p+2]==1 and x[n+1]==1) or (x[n+2] == 1 and x[n+1]==1) or (x[n+p+2]==1 and x[n+1]==1) or (x[n+p+2]==1 and x[n+p+1]==1):
            direc.append(3)
        if x[n+2*p+2] == 1 and x[n+p+1]==1:
            direc.append(4)
        if (x[n+2*p-1]==1 and (x[n+p-1]==1 or x[n+p]==1)) or (x[n+2*p]==1 and x[n+p]==1) or (x[n+2*p+1]==1 and(n[x+p]==1 or n[x+p+1]==1)):
            direc.append(1)
        if x[n+2*p-2]==1 and x[n+p-1]==1:
            direc.append(2)
        if (x[n+p-2]==1 and (x[n+p-1]==1 or x[n-1]==1)) or (x[n-2]==1 and x[n-1]==1) or (x[n-p-2]==1 and (x[n-p-1]==1 or x[n-1]==1)):    
            direc.append(3)
        if x[n-2*p-2]==1 and x[n-p-1]==1:
            direc.append(4)
```

This is line 31 btw (its also in the code above but there are no line numbers there I think)

```
if (x[n+2*p-1]==1 and (x[n+p-1]==1 or x[n+p]==1)) or (x[n+2*p]==1 and x[n+p]==1) or (x[n+2*p+1]==1 and(n[x+p]==1 or n[x+p+1]==1)):
```

---

I didn't post my full code, sorry. Here it comes:

```
fill = "FILLER"
test_list = []
p = 6
pixels = [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,fill,fill,fill,fill,fill,fill,fill,fill,fill,fill,fill,fill,fill,fill]
direc = []
new_direc = []
real_direc = [0]
def organise(x):
for n in range(len(x)-2*p):
    if x[n] !=1:
        direc.append(0)
    else:    
        if (x[n-2*p-1] == 1 and x[n-p-1]==1) or (x[n-2*p-1] == 1 and x[n-p]==1) or (x[n-2*p] == 1 and x[n-p]==1) or (x[n-2*p+1]== 1 and x[n-p]==1) or (x[n-2*p+1]== 1 and x[n-p+1]==1):
            direc.append(1)
        if x[n-2*p+2]== 1 and x[n-p+1]==1: 
            direc.append(2)
        if (x[n-p+2]==1 and x[n-p+1]==1) or (x[n-p+2]==1 and x[n+1]==1) or (x[n+2] == 1 and x[n+1]==1) or (x[n+p+2]==1 and x[n+1]==1) or (x[n+p+2]==1 and x[n+p+1]==1):
            direc.append(3)
        if x[n+2*p+2] == 1 and x[n+p+1]==1:
            direc.append(4)
        if (x[n+2*p-1]==1 and (x[n+p-1]==1 or x[n+p]==1)) or (x[n+2*p]==1 and x[n+p]==1) or (x[n+2*p+1]==1 and(n[x+p]==1 or n[x+p+1]==1)):
            direc.append(1)
        if x[n+2*p-2]==1 and x[n+p-1]==1:
            direc.append(2)
        if (x[n+p-2]==1 and (x[n+p-1]==1 or x[n-1]==1)) or (x[n-2]==1 and x[n-1]==1) or (x[n-p-2]==1 and (x[n-p-1]==1 or x[n-1]==1)):    
            direc.append(3)
        if x[n-2*p-2]==1 and x[n-p-1]==1:
            direc.append(4)

for n in range(len(direc)):
    if direc[n] != 0:
        new_direc.append(direc[n])
for n in range(len(new_direc)-1):
    if new_direc[n] != real_direc[-1]:
        real_direc.append(new_direc[n])
del real_direc[0]        

print direc
print new_direc
print real_direc
return direc
```

Comment: Obviously `n` is an integer as defined in the `for` loop. What does `n[x+p]` mean then?

Comment: Your second problem will then be that `p` is not defined anywhere, unless it's a global.

Answer (score 1):

```
n[x+p]==1 or n[x+p+1]==1
```

This is wrong. It should be x[n] not the other way round.